# Where can I get an up-to-date list of countries that are under US sanctions?

Tags: united-states, sanctions

I am a regular freelancer in a company. I like to travel during work and vacation.
But at my new job, they told me that I can't visit countries that are under US sanctions.
Where can I get this list ? A list of places where from the point of view of the United States it is impossible to go ?

Answer (score 1):

The US has sanctions against the [following countries](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_sanctions):

> Iran
>
> North Korea
>
> Syria
>
> Cuba
>
> Venezuela
>
> Turkey

And combined, the Treasury Department, the Commerce Department and the State Department list embargoes against the following 30 countries or territories:

> Afghanistan, Belarus, Burundi, Central African Republic, China (PR),
> Côte d'Ivoire, Crimea Region, Cuba, Cyprus, Democratic Republic of the
> Congo, Eritrea, Fiji, Haiti, Iran, Iraq, Kyrgyzstan, Laos, Lebanon,
> Liberia, Libya, Myanmar, North Korea, Palestinian Territories, Russia,
> Rwanda, Somalia, South Sudan, Sri Lanka, Sudan, Syria, Venezuela,
> Yemen, Zimbabwe.

However, a sanction or embargo does not necessarily mean travel to that country is prohibited - each will have its own particular set of rules.

For example, notwithstanding any specific Covid restrictions, an American citizen may travel to freely to the [Republic of Cyprus](https://cy.usembassy.gov/covid-19-information/#:%7E:text=U.S.%20citizen%20travelers%20should%20enter,%E2%80%9Clegal%E2%80%9D%20entrance%20into%20Cyprus) but will require State Department permission  to visit [North Korea](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/KoreaDemocraticPeoplesRepublicof.html#:%7E:text=Individuals%20cannot%20use%20a%20U.S.,only%20in%20very%20limited%20circumstances) which is available only in exceptional circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

U.S. Department Of The Treasury [Sanctions Programs and Country Information](https://home.treasury.gov/policy-issues/financial-sanctions/sanctions-programs-and-country-information) page has the list of countries and the sanctions programs active towards them.